# Programmatically trigger jquery dropdown change event as soon as the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

I have 2 dropdownlist that will fire an event if both of them are changed.
(meaning, any changes on the indices will fire a json request that is based on the dropdownlist's current value and append them to my table).

My question is that,as soon as the page loaded, are there any ways to pre-select their indices and fire the event at the same time? I am planning to set them based on the current term and school year.

Here is my jquery code:

```
$schoolyear = $('select#schoolyear');
$schoolterm = $('select#schoolterm')
$tbl = $('#classview');

$schoolyear.change(function () {
getCL();
});

$schoolterm.change(function () {
getCL();
});


function getCL() {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("getClassList","Enrollment")', { term: $schoolterm.val(), year: $schoolyear.val() }, function (e) {

                $tbl.find('tbody').remove();

                if (e.length > 0) {

                    $(e).each(function (index, e) {
                        $tbl.append('<tr><td>' + e.subj + '</td><td>' + e.days + '</td><td>' + e.cstart + '</td><td>' + e.cend + '</td><td>' + e.professor + '</td><td>' + e.units + '</td><td>' + e.status +
                        '</td>' + '<td>' + '<form action="/Enrollment/dropClass" method="post">' + '<input type="hidden" name="test"  value="'+e.id+'"/>' +
                        '<a href="#"> Delete </a>' + '</form></td></tr>')

                    });
                }
                else {
                    $tbl.append('<tr><td colspan="8">No match found</td></tr>');
                }
                //compute t
            });
  }
```

Comment: could you not just run `getCL()` when the page is loaded?

Comment: hmm i see, that might work. `getCL` gets the value of the dropdownlist anyway, how do i set the dropdownlist's value since `getCL` base it from that?

Comment: `$schoolyear.val('someValue')`

Comment: ahhhhhh alright, thank you

Comment: Or if the default value will always be the same, just add `selected="selected"` to the default option then call `$schoolyear.change()` on load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can trigger the change on one of them while setting value

```
var now = new Date();
var year = now.getFullYear();
var month = now.getMonth();
var term = Math.ceil(month/4);// needs verification on how term is set

$schoolyear
    .change(getCL)
    .val(year);//set year value

$schoolterm
    .change(getCL)
      // trigger change after setting value, will call getCL()
    .val(term).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try just adding `getCL()` at the bottom of your script.

```
$schoolyear = $('select#schoolyear');
$schoolterm = $('select#schoolterm')
$tbl = $('#classview');

$schoolyear.change(function () {
getCL();
});

$schoolterm.change(function () {
getCL();
});

function getCL() {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("getClassList","Enrollment")', { term: $schoolterm.val(), year: $schoolyear.val() }, function (e) {

                $tbl.find('tbody').remove();

                if (e.length > 0) {

                    $(e).each(function (index, e) {
                        $tbl.append('<tr><td>' + e.subj + '</td><td>' + e.days + '</td><td>' + e.cstart + '</td><td>' + e.cend + '</td><td>' + e.professor + '</td><td>' + e.units + '</td><td>' + e.status +
                        '</td>' + '<td>' + '<form action="/Enrollment/dropClass" method="post">' + '<input type="hidden" name="test"  value="'+e.id+'"/>' +
                        '<a href="#"> Delete </a>' + '</form></td></tr>')

                    });
                }
                else {
                    $tbl.append('<tr><td colspan="8">No match found</td></tr>');
                }
                //compute t
            });
  }

getCL();  //this will run once when page is loaded.
```

To answer your other question, you can set a default pre-selected option in the dropdown by adding `selected` to your dropdown. For example:

```
<select>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2013" selected>2013</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
```